# NAPS2 Auto detect image when scanning

Tags: scanner, ocr, scanning

Is there any way to detect image. I have HP LaserJet Pro MFP M28 printer/scanner and I have some pictures with different sizes to scan. Can I set up NAPS2 to automatically detect image from whole canvas?

Comment: HP's own 'HP Easy Scan' app is smart enough to crop to photo edges when set to capture as 'Photos, Graphics, etc'

Answer (score 0):

ABBYY Finereader can separately detect photos, text, tables etc. and you can edit/delete them as in Adobe Acrobat. You can use the software directly for scanning.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).